# windows azure WCF multiple x509 certificate error

Tags: wcf, azure, certificate, x509certificate

We are using windows azure web role for hosting WCF service. This WCF service has Certificate authentication enabled.
The RootCertificate and Server certificate are uploaded to hosted service - certificate section. During deployment, these certificates are automatically installed on Azure role's CurrentUser, My store.

Everything is working fine. Problem starts when we upgrade our service. After upgrading, occupationally get multiple x509 certificate error. We are finding certificate by thumbprint, then there should not be any chance of finding certificate by multiple thumbprint.

Somebody has faced similar problem but there is no solution posted for it. please refer
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/aa2ce0e3-4ee7-4d6e-8ea8-0ac1f75e912b/

Web.config file as below. I have removed actual thumbprint value.

```
  <behavior name="customBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom"
                          customCertificateValidatorType="CCP.Hosting.Provisioning.WebRole.Authentication.Implementation.X509CertificateValidator,CCP.Hosting.Provisioning.WebRole"
                          revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
        </clientCertificate> 
        <serviceCertificate
          findValue="{ThumbPrint}"
          x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"
          storeLocation="CurrentUser"
          storeName="My"/>
      </serviceCredentials>

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="customWsHttpBinding" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="400000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="5000000" maxStringContentLength="50000000"
      maxArrayLength="50000000" maxBytesPerRead="50000000" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<services>
  <service name="CCP.Hosting.Provisioning.WebRole.ProvisioningService" behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior" >
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customWsHttpBinding"
      address="" contract="CCP.Provisioning.Web.Interfaces.IProvisioningService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Occasionally we get below error. I have removed thumbprint from below error.

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 7/11/2012 11:51:16 AM 
Event time (UTC): 7/11/2012 11:51:16 AM 
Event ID: 841596aaed284171896138a00b734fe3 
Event sequence: 2 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1273337584/ROOT-1-129864806465987458 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: E:\sitesroot\0\ 
    Machine name: RD00155D3AAD31 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 3432 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Found multiple X.509 certificates using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'CurrentUser', FindType 'FindByThumbprint', FindValue '{Thumbprint}'. Provide a more specific find value.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.GetCertificateFromStoreCore(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, X509FindType findType, Object findValue, EndpointAddress target, Boolean throwIfMultipleOrNoMatch)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.GetCertificateFromStore(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, X509FindType findType, Object findValue, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.X509RecipientCertificateServiceElement.ApplyConfiguration(X509CertificateRecipientServiceCredential cert)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceCredentialsElement.ApplyConfiguration(ServiceCredentials behavior)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceCredentialsElement.CreateBehavior()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadBehaviors[T](ServiceModelExtensionCollectionElement`1 behaviorElement, KeyedByTypeCollection`1 behaviors, Boolean commonBehaviors)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Unity.Wcf.UnityServiceHost..ctor(IUnityContainer container, Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Unity.Wcf.UnityServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://abcd.cloudapp.net/blahblah.svc 
    Request path: /ProvisioningService.svc 
    User host address: 210.18.83.151 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 8 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.GetCertificateFromStoreCore(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, X509FindType findType, Object findValue, EndpointAddress target, Boolean throwIfMultipleOrNoMatch)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.GetCertificateFromStore(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, X509FindType findType, Object findValue, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.X509RecipientCertificateServiceElement.ApplyConfiguration(X509CertificateRecipientServiceCredential cert)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceCredentialsElement.ApplyConfiguration(ServiceCredentials behavior)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceCredentialsElement.CreateBehavior()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadBehaviors[T](ServiceModelExtensionCollectionElement`1 behaviorElement, KeyedByTypeCollection`1 behaviors, Boolean commonBehaviors)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Unity.Wcf.UnityServiceHost..ctor(IUnityContainer container, Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Unity.Wcf.UnityServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
```

Comment: Have you checked the certificate store to see if there exists multiple certificates with the same thumbprint value?

Comment: Its only single certificate. I believe we can not install certificate with same thumbprint at same location. It gets overwrittern

Comment: Just write a test client to get the certificates from the store based on thumbprint value and cross check if the count is 1. Would be worth trying. Make sure of the account you are using to access the cert store

Comment: Yes, count is one only. I have verified with test app.

Comment: What do you mean by upgrade the service?

Comment: Service is already deployed in azure. Next time you deploy, you can upgrade the service without recreating roles.

Comment: Check this link which might be helpful : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-SE/windowsazuresecurity/thread/63ada2f6-ecd2-4cfd-8605-699cbbb111c8

Comment: I am running into exact same issue.  Haven't found any solution yet.  The certificate i am dealing with goes to CurrentUser.

Comment: The solution is to install certificate in local machine store rather than current user. You may have to use startup tasks to install cert in certain areas of local machine store.